# Nodes in 2-D heat plate -- Matrix Solving -- Laplace Equation - Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I do not understand why Matlab is giving me the " Index exceeds Matrix dimensions"

```
    j = 1;
    for i = 1:Nx;
    n = i+(j-1)*Nx;
    M(n,n) = 1;
    B(n,1) = bottom_boundary(i);
    end
```

I am probably just being really stupid and not seeing the error but my logic seems to be correct. It lets me loop through the for loop the first time and places the value in B(1,1) when n = 1. When n = 5, it gives me the error that the index exceeds matrix dimensions. B is a 16x1 row vector.
[Workspace - Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxBwT.png)

Comment: What is the output of    bottom_boundary function?  is it always a number not a vector regardless i value?

Comment: bottom_boundary is always the temperature at the bottom of the plate -- it will always be a scalar value.

Comment: I am about to try to pass it as an anonymous function so that bottom_boundary = @ (i) temperature_of_boundary (i)

Comment: The problem is for sure from @bottom_boundary function. If you just replace by a number, you loop works.